# Probability Question A fair coin is tossed repeatedly until a head appears

Tags: probability

Can you help me with this.

A fair coin is tossed repeatedly until a head appears. Let $N$ be the number of
trials until the rst head appears. Then a fair die is rolled $N$ times. Let $X$ be the number of times that the die comes up $4$. Calculate $P\{X = 0\}$,  $P\{X = 1\}$ and $E[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

> A fair coin is tossed repeatedly until a head appears. Let N  be the number of trials until the rst head appears. Then a fair die is rolled N  times. Let X  be the number of times that the die comes up 4 . Calculate P{X=0} , P{X=1}  and E[X] .

$\begin{align}N\sim {\cal Geo}(1/2) &\iff \mathsf P(N=n) = 2^{-n} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{\{0\ldots\infty\}}(n)
\\[1ex]
(X\mid N=n) \sim {\cal Bin}(n, 1/6) &\iff \mathsf P(X=x\mid N=n) = {n\choose x}5^{n-x}6^{-n}\operatorname{\bf 1}_{\{0\ldots n\}}(x)
\\[1ex]
\mathsf P(X=x) & = \sum_{n=x}^\infty \mathsf P(X=x\mid N=n)\,\mathsf P(N=n)
\\ & =\sum_{n=0}^\infty {n\choose x}\frac{5^{n-x}}{12^n}\operatorname{\bf 1}_{\{0\ldots n\}}(x)
\\ & = \frac{\operatorname{\bf 1}_{\{0\ldots\infty\}}(x)}{5^x}\sum_{n=x}^\infty {n\choose x}\frac{5^{n}}{12^n}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E[X] & = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x}{5^x}\sum_{n=x}^\infty {n\choose x}\frac{5^{n}}{12^n}
\\ & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{5^{n}}{12^n}\sum_{x=0}^n {n\choose x}\frac{x}{5^x}
\end{align}$

Can you find closed forms to complete?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $N$ follows a [geometric law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter 1/2.

So start computing conditionally to the value of $N(\omega)$.

Then compute the average according to the law of $N$.